# Is there an equivalent setting in Eevee as Glossy Direct in Cycles engine?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, lighting, render-passes, viewlayers

I'm trying to follow the Blender Guru donut tutorial but using Eevee to render. I'm trying to add a glowy nature to the white highlights on the object. The Glossy<Light<Passes<ViewLayerProperties isn't present for Eevee so is there an alternative route I can use here?

Answer (score -2):

Switch to Cycles briefly and then enable *Glossy Direct*. Then render the image, and then switch back to EEVEE.